# Image is disappearing with same uri

Tags: react-native

I am running sample application. I am using [amazon s3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3) to store the profile pics. So, I have to use the same url for the profile pictures. I give the Image a unique key prop to try and get it to reload the image, but it displays a previously uploaded image. It means cache is not cleared for image component.

I tried this below code. Image should be updated perfectly but any changes doing in that screen then image will be disappearing.

This issue only appears  in **android**.

```
 <Image
    source={{uri: this.state.uri + '?' + new Date()}}
    />
```

Please refer this link:- [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12606#issuecomment-451653768)

Screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: easy, because every `setState` trigger re-render the DOM, you should use `componentWillUpdate` to avoid it

Comment: use whole url from state, change the state whenever neccessary but do not use date() in props directly.

Answer (score 1):

set a local const variable as

```
const url = {uri: this.state.uri + '?' + new Date()};
```

Use the url as follows:

```
<Image
source={uri}
/>
```

Comment: Hi Harika, Where did u place that const variable??
If possible share complete code

Comment: i set a local variable and it calls in image component
like below code
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      avatarSource: "url",
      spinner: false
    });
  }
render(){
const url = {uri:this.state.avatarSource}
return(
<Image
source={{uri:url.uri}}
/>
)
}

Comment: Don't set the value in state call it directly